# Should I connect all database tables to base user, or just 1?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have an app that companies can subscribe to.The company details are kept on a company table: `companyId | name | email | subscriptionType | lastPaid`

Each company has employees in the employee table: `employeeId | name | company`

If I have another table, for -say- shifts, should that shift table also have a reference to the company each shift is for, or just to the employees?

`shiftStart | shiftEnd | employeeId` or `shiftStart | shiftEnd | employeeId | company`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with just employeeId (your first example)

We know which company the employee works for from the Employee table and would add the company table using a join in a query if it was required.

Adding the companyId to the shifts table is just introducing an unnecessary opportunity for error.